# How to take a bit of path from the whole path in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a path like `C:\APP\local\` and I need only the `C:\APP` to one variable. How can I achieve this in my vb.net code. Please help me in getting the only the path `C:\APP` to the variable.

I haven't tried anything yet, I am bit confused so..!!

I have a file name = `C:\APP\Local\`. It's a default value how can I get the 
`filename1 = "C:\APP"`, please help me to write the code.

I don't have any errors.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i have just added some more content to the question

Comment: You may find help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710170/java-use-regex-to-extract-file-name

Comment: For begining, search about `.ToString().Split()` function, or just about `Split` function in vb.net

Comment: uh... like this `Dim filename1 As String = "C:\APP"`

Comment: It's not clear if you want to keep the first folder or remove the last folder.

Comment: yes i want to keep first folder and remove the last folder

Comment: @chandu I think you misunderstood. Suppose the string is "C:\APP\local\folder\"; do you want to keep only the first folder (resulting in "C:\APP\") or remove only the last folder (resulting in C:\APP\local\")?

Comment: i just want to keep only C:\APP i dont want the other thing

Answer (score 1):

Use the Path class that already available in VB

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(yourPath)
```

Similarly you can use

```
Path.GetExtension(yourPath)
Path.GetFileName(yourPath)
Path.GetFullPath(yourPath)
Path.GetPathRoot(yourPath)
```

To get other information you may need from your path

Comment: I was going to suggest something like this, but after reading his question from left to right, right to left, and standing on my head, I just cant tell what he's after

Comment: In question is provided example where both, `APP` and `local`, are folders so any of your solution will not give him desired result. Anyway, he is little confused about that what is file and what is folder, because there's no filename in example.